# Pulling cPanel awstats into custom CMS using php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to find the best method, if any, for pulling in some basic web stat info into a custom cms. Basically, I'd like for clients to be able to see a quick view of their latest web stats.

So far I've been able to come up with one solution using `file_get_contents` and pretty sure I can run with this and do some parsing to get the info I need.

I also was playing with cURL but was a little stumped after getting past the cPanel login.

My question would be what is the best method, if any, for pulling awstats with php to display in a custom view?

Here is an example with `file_get_contents`

```
$username = '';
$password = '';
$url = '';
$year = 2016;
$url = "http://".$username.":".$password."@".$url.":2082/awstats.pl?month=03&year="
                .$year."&config=".$url."&lang=en&framename=mainright&output=main";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
echo $html;
```

Here is my attempt using cURL

```
$domain = '';
$post = array();
$post['user'] = '';
$post['pass'] = '';
$post['goto_uri'] = '/';
$post['login_theme'] = 'cpanel';
$url = 'http://'.$domain.':2082/login/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = strstr($response, 'URL=/');
$response = strstr($response, '/frontend/', true);
$response = substr($response,5);
$url = 'http://'.$domain.':2082/'.$response.'/awstats.pl?config='.$domain.'&ssl=&lang=en';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

However, this outputs the login screen again..